# Select Node by Variable in Grouping

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

For the grouping function, is there a way to group by dynamic key, which is passed in the input data? For example, in the input xml below, I want to group `<Trans>` by the node name passed in `<key1>`, which is currently "id". Thank you!

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Trans" group-by="[this key node name is from the input]">
```

Input xml:

```
<File>
    <key1>id</key1>
    <Trans>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>jane</name>
        <location>ga</location>
        <value>1.11</value>
    </Trans>
    <Trans>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>jane</name>
        <location>ma</location>
        <value>2.22</value>
    </Trans>
    <Trans>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>john</name>
        <location>al</location>
        <value>3.33</value>
    </Trans>
    <Trans>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>jj</name>
        <location>ga</location>
        <value>4.44</value>
    </Trans> </File>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`group-by="*[local-name() = ../key1]"`